# General report of a couple tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, report, sql-server-2014

I need to create a general report of the following table schema:

[image: Table Schema]

I need to create the following table for the general report:

```
+----------+--------+------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------+
| Location | Trucks | TotalOfCampaings | CampaingsWithCompleteStatus | CampaingsWithInProcessStatus |
+----------+--------+------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------+
|          |        |                  |                             |                              |
+----------+--------+------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------+
|          |        |                  |                             |                              |
+----------+--------+------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------+
```

- **Location**: Location of the trucks with at least one campaing.
- **Trucks**: Number of Trucks by Location with at least one campaing.
- **TotalOfCampaings**: Total Number of Campaings by the Location and Trucks.
- **CampaingsWithCompleteStatus**: Total Number of Campaings Completed, the status are in the Campaing Table.
- **CampaingsWithInProcessStatus**: Total Number of Campaings with in process status, the status are in the Campaing Table.

**Campaing = Order to fix one or multiple trucks.**

I tried with a inner joins, but i can't get what i expect for the general report.

I would appreciate help me with this, any question post on comments!

Comment: Can you post the query that you tried, the result, and what you want to be different?  This will help us a lot!

Comment: @HurricaneDevelopment Hi, the situation is the following, i already created a report for the same problem , but the scheme change and now i need to modify to the new scheme, the only change was that the status field change of the **campaign control** table to the **campaign** table.

Comment: @HurricaneDevelopment wait a second, let me find my previous code

Comment: @HurricaneDevelopment [link](https://s16.postimg.org/qosubd3v9/code.png) Chek the code in the link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT Truck.location as Location,
    COUNT(Truck.vin) as Trucks,
    COUNT(Campaing.campaing_id) as TotalOfCampaings,
    sum(case when Campaing.campaing_estatus = 'Complete' then 1 else 0 end) as CampaingsWithCompleteStatus,
    sum(case when Campaing.campaing_estatus = 'InProcess' then 1 else 0 end) as CampaingsWithInProcessStatus
    FROM CampaingControl
        INNER JOIN Truck ON CampaingControl.vin = Truck.vin
        INNER JOIN Campaing ON CampaingControl.campaing_id = Campaing.campaing_id
    GROUP BY Truck.location;
```

Comment: When i tried to test, this failure in the second inner join

Comment: This: Incorrect syntax near the keyword ' INNER ' . But is in the second inner join.

Comment: Hmm, I did update the post to remove a comma, try again?